# Firestore offline scenario with user permissions

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How are document permissions handled in Firestore's offline layer when coming online, depending on who created them.

#### Scenario

A user updates a document while offline, *that only he has permissions to update*. He logs out. Device goes online. A new user logs in. Will Firestore throw a permission denied error when it tries to upload the document updated while offline?

The security rule could be a simple as:

```
match /users/{userUid} {
  allow update: if request.auth.uid == userUid;
}
```

Does Firestore cache the user who created each document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security rules are evaluated on the server.  That's the only way they can truly be secure.  There are no controls implemented on the client.  If a user happens to modify a document locally, that modification will appear to take place when inspecting locally cached data, but will fail on the server at the time of synchronization.

Comment: Some additional notes: if the operation gets rejected on the server, the client will then fire reconciliation events on the client to correct the state. So if you [listen for changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) and got a `change.type === "added"` for a document write that actually isn't allowed by security rules, you'll get a `change.type === "removed"` when the write has been rejected by the server.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson So in regards to my example above, you're saying that the server *will* reject the document, even though it was valid for the user who created it?

Comment: The client SDK can only use the credentials of the currently logged in user.  If the current user can't make the change, then it's not valid.

Comment: Alright, I guess that's how it is then. But consider this a feature request for the above scenario then. Our app is multi-user on one device; so the above is not unlikely.

Comment: Please file any feature requests with Firebase support: https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support